# No overload for method 'Range' takes 4 arguments [Assembly-CSharp]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
float random;
void Start () 
{   
    random = Random.Range(-2,21f, 1,53f);
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, random);
}
```

Comment: use `.` instead of `,`

Comment: thank you, finally it works. sorry i am a beginner @Crowcoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use , to make a number with decimals. Because C# thinks you are actually imputing 4 numbers instead of 2.

**Example Code:**

```
random = Random.Range(-2.21f, 1.53f);
```